# Post with average comments per hour

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT p.*,
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    count(c.comment_post_id) AS comments
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN comments AS c
    ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id)
LEFT JOIN users AS u
    ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id)
WHERE c.comment_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
GROUP BY p.post_id    
ORDER BY count(c.comment_post_id) DESC
```

This makes a list of posts sorted by most comments the last hour. The problem now is that the posts with 0 comments last hour does not make the list.

So is there a way to make it ordered by average comment per hour since the comment was created? This way all the posts will make the list, and the most discussed posts will always be on top.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/820044/1/0

EDIT:

```
SELECT p.*, u.user_id, u.user_name, COUNT(c.comment_post_id) / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, p.post_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) AS rate FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id) LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id) GROUP BY p.post_id ORDER BY COUNT(c.comment_post_id) / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, p.post_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) DESC
```

This is what solved the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sqlfiddle?

Comment: I dont know, never done it before. Looking into it now.

Comment: If you provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ people can easier test you're code. Therefore you've a bigger change that you're question will be answered!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/820044/1/0 is this the info you need?

Comment: Yes. The next time please put the link in you're question and put some fake data into it. Put in you're question also a excepted output. With that people can immediately help you without wasting to much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select only posts that have comments within one hour, because of the `WHERE` clause. What you can try is:

```
SELECT p.*,
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    SUM(c.comment_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS comments
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN comments AS c
    ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id)
LEFT JOIN users AS u
    ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id)
GROUP BY p.post_id    
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(c.comment_post_id) / 
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, p.post_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) DESC
```

For each comment that is within the hour the boolean expression `c.comment_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` will contribute one to the `SUM(...)`.

For the second part, we can find how many hours passed from publishing a post with `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, p.post_timestamp, SYSDATE())`. So dividing the number of comments with the number of hours, gives us the sorting criterion. But we add one to the hours to avoid division by zero.

Comment: This solves the immediate problem. Have linked to sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/820044/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Bit hard to see without the data, but to solve your immediate problem (i.e. get the zero-recent-comments posts showing), don't you just want to move your constraint into the `LEFT JOIN`?

```
LEFT JOIN comments AS c
    ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id AND c.comment_added > NOW - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```